# Spring XD - Module "source:trigger" does not work as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I'm a bit confused on how the module "source:trigger" should work in Spring XD. Based on the documentation, you can provide a start date and a fixed delay, and theoretically the stream that defines the trigger should only start at that time and repeat itself based on the fixed delay.

For example:

```
stream create --name s1 --definition "trigger --date='12/08/14 23:35:00' --fixedDelay=10 | log" --deploy
```

When deployed, this stream is expected to be fired for the very first time exactly at 23:35:00 on the 12/08/14 (using a date format = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"); however, it's fired just after it is deployed, no matter what the time is:

```
23:33:28,409 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.DeploymentListener - Deploying module 'trigger' for stream 's1'
23:33:28,572 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.DeploymentListener - Deploying module [ModuleDescriptor@760ca434 moduleName = 'trigger', moduleLabel = 'trigger', group = 's1', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = source, parameters = map['date' -> '12/08/14 23:35:00', 'fixedDelay' -> '10'], children = list[[empty]]]
23:33:28,946 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:33:28,954 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO Deployer server.StreamDeploymentListener - Deployment status for stream 's1': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
23:33:28,955 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO Deployer server.StreamDeploymentListener - Stream Stream{name='s1'} deployment attempt complete
```

As the logs show, stream "s1" is actually started off at 23:33:28, sooner than expected. Once started, it repeats every 10 seconds as configured in the fixed delay:

```
23:33:38,952 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:33:48,956 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:33:58,961 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-4 sink.s1 - 
23:34:08,966 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-2 sink.s1 - 
23:34:18,969 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-2 sink.s1 - 
23:34:28,973 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:34:38,974 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:34:48,979 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:34:58,984 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:35:08,989 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:35:18,993 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-9 sink.s1 - 
23:35:28,998 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:35:39,003 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:35:49,009 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:35:59,013 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:36:09,017 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 - 
23:36:19,022 1.1.0.SNAP  INFO task-scheduler-1 sink.s1 -
```

Therefore, why is this stream not taking into account the "date" parameter, but just fires whenever it's deployed? Is this a bug or the expected behaviour in Spring XD? If the latter, how can I set up such a trigger so it only fires at a given time?

BTW, I started up Spring XD setting the system property "user.timezone" to "CET", just to make sure that Spring XD uses the same TimeZone I'm working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind pointing to the documentation out? Actually I don't see good documentation for that module even in the latest SNAPSHOT.

The `source:trigger` module is based on 3 profiles: `date`, `cron` or `fixedDelay`. The last one has precedence over the first `TriggerSourceOptionsMetadata`:

```
@Override
public String[] profilesToActivate() {
    if (cron != null) {
        return new String[] { "use-cron" };
    }
    else if (fixedDelay != null) {
        return new String[] { "use-delay" };
    }
    else {
        return new String[] { "use-date" };
    }
}
```

I guess you want to use `PeriodicTrigger#initialDelay`. Unfortunately that Spring option isn't exposed as XD option.

I don't see any out-of-the-box way to overcome your requirements, rather than some customization to that module with the `initialDelay` option for the `use-delay` profile.

Feel free to raise [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD) issue regarding documentation for `source:trigger` and support for `initialDelay`.

Comment: So based on that code, it means that they cannot be combined, can they? Thanks for the response.

Comment: No, they can't. Actually we should improve `TriggerSourceOptionsMetadata#isValid()` that all those options are mutually exclusive. Please, raise an issue to address them all.

Comment: Also created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2482 to add support for "initialDelay"